# How to change the Img tag src through css only?

Tags: css

How can I replace the image tag src value through css ? and i want support in ie8 ,firefox ,chorme,safari

```
<div class="any">
 <img src="images/i.png"/>
</div>
```

replace this src value through css only.

Thanks

Comment: You can't. It's not CSS.

Comment: you can do this via javascript

Comment: This cannot be done with CSS, it will require scripting (either server-, or client-, side). *Edited* okay, in Chrome 28 this seems to be possible (somehow): [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/AwdMS/). Cross-browser seems unlikely at best.

Comment: oopsy....not feasible Ankit.... Use java-script to dynamically assign value to src attribute.

Comment: @DavidThomas: doesn't work in Firefox 22

Comment: @Andreas: I'm entirely surprised that it works in Chrome; I have absolutely no expectation that it's either an expected behaviour or cross-browser supported.

Comment: Well this is something new...woo, cross-browser seems to spin my head...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try setting a background image and then moving (with padding) out of the box the original image

something like this...

**EDIT** i had to tweak it a bit to have it working...

```
.any img {
  display: block;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: url(http://placehold.it/150) no-repeat;
  width: 150px; 
  height: 150px;  
  padding-left: 150px; 
}
```

... and here is the working example
http://jsfiddle.net/nNaRn/1/

Comment: can you please explain the box-sizing property?

Comment: `box-sizing` refers to the box model used. `border-box` tells the browser that the `width` and `height` size include `padding` and `border`. Without it, it defaults to `content-box`, which tells the browser to consider `width` to be the content's width, and it will add `padding` and `border` size to obtain the final box width.

Comment: See http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/ for a case against `content-box`

Comment: vote up if is useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the src tag of the image with CSS, because the image src is nothing to do with CSS.

The closest you can do is set the background image of the div and get rid of the img tag altogether:

```
.any {
    background-image: url('images/myimage.png');
}
```

Beyond this, you will need to use Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the src through CSS.  Although what you can do is define a blank div, and give it a width, height, and background-image through CSS.  The only drawback with that approach is that the element will not behave like an image for the user (drag/drop, rightclick to save, etc.).

```
div.any {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url('./some-url-that-you-can-override-by-another-stylesheet');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that you can do is to set `background-image` to `.any` and `display:none` to `img` but you will need to set also `width` and `height` of the div, since div without content have width of 100%, and height of 0.

```
.any {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-image: url(image/1.gif);
}
.any img {
    display: none;
}
```